# How to fix antd babel import css overrides custom css?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, antd

In my react app i have imported antd components and using babel import to lazy load css styles.

```
['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }, "antd"]
```

I have some custom scss styles that overrides antd component styles.

In the development, my custom scss overrides antd styles perfectly.

But when I run npm build, it happens the opposite, antd overrides my custom styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I fixed the issue. The documentation https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import helped me to fix the issue.

I have used `style: true`, which imports source files. I have changed it to `style: 'css'` which imports precompiled css

```
['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: 'css' }, "antd"]
```

This worked for me. My custom scss styles overrides antd styles on build.

Comment: If we go this way, we won't be to overwrite global LESS variables. Correct? We would need to overwrite each and every required CSS then.